# Different babel or webpack configuration based on entry point

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

In my application, I am applying `babel` using `webpack` (which I use to generate my bundles from my source files). I create one bundle that runs on the server (entry point `server_rendering.js`) in an ExecJS environment and another that runs on the client (entry point `application.js`). Due to some peculiar interactions with certain JS libraries, I need to run different babel transformations dependent on the entry point file. How might I do this?

To clarify, there seem to be a number of similar questions concerned with `babel` responding differently based on environment variables which is *not* what I want to do here. I want to be able to compile both files as part of the same `webpack` process.

In my situation, I could *also* be satisfied with augmenting my `webpack` configuration based on the entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need multiple Webpack configs, for example by returning an array of configs from `webpack.config.js`. Webpack can't do what you ask with one config because entrypoints are just that, *entry* points into *one* application. A given file will only be compiled a single time within an application, so there isn't any way to compile the same file multiple ways.

How you integrate that with Babel is up to you, but you could for instance pass `envName: "client"` to `babel-loader` in your client-side Webpack config, and `envName: "server"` to Babel your server Webpack config. Then your Babel config can select the set of plugins based on that value.